# What is the criteria for feeding berries?

Tags: pokemon-go

I like feeding Pokemon with berries on gyms. However, it is not always allowed to feed them.

I already know that you cant feed more than 10 in a certain period of time. I also know that you can't keep feeding the same Pokemon over and over again. what are the limits for feeding berries to Pokemon in gyms?

Comment: Doesn't my answer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/315696/162442) answer this question?

Comment: @Vemonus Not completely: It's not just that; I think there is some inter-player interaction that affects it as well

Comment: what makes you think that though? Everything is pretty much explained in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6n0i3w/a_detailed_look_at_the_berry_feeding_limit/)...

Comment: @Vemonus You didn't really cover the second part (probably because when you answered it wasn't known), so I answered separately here - but the Silph Road thread certainly covers it.

Comment: @Joe you realize the link is the one I used in my answer, right? And that the passage I quoted was from it as well?

Comment: @Vemonus Yes - see my comment just before you.  You don't mention the 10 unique pokemon (but the thread does, so I wonder if it wasn't known when you originally posted).  Though there's no edit mark on the reddit post so perhaps it was and you just didn't think it was relevant to the other question.

Comment: @Vemonus , the q to your a asks for just the cooldown time. I'm asking for ALL criteria

Comment: I do think that the other question is different than this, btw; this is focusing on when you get the messages saying you can't feed berries.  That one is focusing on the diminishing returns on motivation.  I think in the current meta, the former is more important (particularly tomorrow for Community day) since many people only use berries for stardust returns (perhaps excepting EX raids).

Comment: @Joe yeah I see your point, they're just really similar and it's a little weird to have two questions that are answerable by the same passages from the same link...

Answer (score 6):

The limits, for one trainer:

- 10 berries per Pokémon per half hour, fixed window (so it resets after 30 minutes after the first Pokémon was fed)
- Any number of Berries to ten unique Pokémon per half hour, rolling window (so each time it's been 30 minutes since you fed a Pokémon, a new one is eligible)

As you feed a Pokémon, each successive berry after the first restores less health; this is reset after thirty minutes as well (with the fixed window).

There are no known limits per Pokémon for multiple trainers: I have seen spoofed gyms being defended prior to legendary or EX raids where clearly dozens of bot-trainers are feeding berries to the same Blissey.

See [this answer by Vemonus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/317856/51234) and the similarly linked [Silph Road thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6n0i3w/a_detailed_look_at_the_berry_feeding_limit/) for more details.

Comment: Citation???????

Comment: @VortexYT Last paragraph.

Comment: How about candies? Sometimes after I feed the pokemon it gives candies, is that random? Or is there some pattern for candies during feeding?

Comment: @alvas That sounds like a good question to ask if it’s own.